# How to handle transient Class Loading error such as thread interrupt

Tags: java, network-programming, classloader, interrupted-exception

So I have a `ClassLoader` descendant that goes through the network to load required classes. How to properly handle transient errors (such as, temporary network outage) or a timeout where thread is interrupted?

The problem here is, the only thing I can throw out of `loadClass()` is `ClassNotFoundException`. It seems that JVM will not reattempt to load class once CNFE is thrown, instead it will fire `NoClassDefFoundError` out of java code.

That's logical, but does not account for transient errors. If we threw CNFE from Class Loader it means the class will never be available and code will never work properly, even if the problem is resolved and class could be loaded on retry. Prolonged waiting from class loading code is undesirable and not always possible.

To make matters worse, it is possible for Class Loader to be interrupted. It will cause InterruptedException on network operation waiting, which in turn will necessitate throwing CNFE, again leading to unusable state where perfectly fine class is not loaded and never will and code is broken.

Is there a recommended solution here on how to handle transient class loading failures? I would prefer the code to get `ClassNoDefFoundError` once but have a retry next time it is needed.

Basically I have two ideas:

- We could mark class loader as bad as soon it suffers from transient error, phase out its usage and create a fresh one which may reattempt loading this class.
- (even more partial) We could clear interrupted flag from thread and wait for the class to be loaded anyway, then restore interrupted flag on thread.

Maybe I'm even wrong and JVM is not normally supposed to throw `NoClassDefFoundError` without going to class loader every time?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem here is, the only thing I can throw out of loadClass() is
>   ClassNotFoundException

Have you tried throwing some unchecked exception? Wonder how the VM will handle that.

> I would prefer the code to get `ClassNoDefFoundError` once but have a
>   retry next time it is needed

So you'd be fine with an arbitrary (number of) thread(s) aborting at an arbitrary point due to a `ClassDefNotFoundError` (notice the `Error` suffix...) as long as other threads retry the class loading later?

It seems that `ClassDefNotFoundError`, also by its name, is considered unrecoverable, which makes sense for most applications.

Comment: Well, when you have application that runs tasks, Error will terminate one task but will not cause the whole application to shut down. In a large system, `ClassDefNotFoundError` is definitely not a show stopper.

Comment: @alamar Indeed, it's not a show stopper, *if* the application is *prepared* to handle those exceptions. In these cases, classes are usually loaded *explicitly* (`Class.forName(...)`,...) and this failing is handled appropriately. But because some class loading error can basically happen *anywhere* in the code, normal applications aren't prepared to try and recover from that error at *every* point where it could theoretically happen.

Comment: Well, you usually have a large catching net at the bottom of stack which will handle such errors and queue the whole task for subsequent retry or fail it. The problem with Class.forName() is that most of its dependencies are loaded lazily and they can still shoot anywhere.